# WAMP allow access to aliases

Tags: apache, wamp

When i try to access phpmyadmin and wamp/www directory - it works fine.
Only when I try to access some other directory like c:/proj , browser returns me

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /proj/index.html on this server.

I didn't find any problems as mine at all. Only alike, when users can't access the page from another lan computer. But use only one computer which is running on Windows 7.

Comment: on the tray icon click and put online to access from lan computer

Comment: @TotPeRo, it is online already

Comment: Show how you created the Alias please. You should not have access to the `C:/proj` unless you specifically grants that access.

Comment: You need to explicitly allow access to folders in your local file system. Just pointing to some folder with an ``Alias`` is _not_ enough. Take a look at the `<Directory>` directive.